# How to undo deregister script and use local versions?

Tags: jquery, wp-enqueue-script

The WordPress theme I am using deregisters the jQuery and jQuery UI libraries and registers google-hosted versions instead of the libraries from wp-includes. Here is the code in `functions.
UPDATE:

```
function w3t_add_scripts() {
    $options = get_option('lollipop');
    global $data; //get theme options

    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');    
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui');

    // Site wide js
    wp_enqueue_script('modernizr', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/modernizr.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('customscript', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/customscript.js');

    //Slider
    if($options['w3t_featured_slider'] == '1') {
    //  if(is_front_page() || is_page()) {
            wp_enqueue_script('cslider', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.cslider.js');
    //  }
    }

    //Lightbox
    if($options['w3t_lightbox'] == '1') {
        wp_enqueue_script('prettyPhoto', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js');
    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','w3t_add_scripts');
```

That's how the entire function looks like now. i did what you suggested, but it's not loading the jquery or jquer-ui files

Comment: what do you mean by local version?

Comment: already available version in wordpress, there are right ?

Comment: just remove all code then

Comment: did. it refuses to load the local version

Comment: Then it/a plug-in must be doing something similar elsewhere or else directly embedding the scripts. CDN copy isn't used by WordPress unless something tells it too..

Comment: it's fresh wordpress installation with no plugin right now. testing on my localhost

Comment: Get a better Theme. This one is `_doing_it_wrong()` at least two major ways (not wrapping the enqueues in a callback, and deregistering core-bundled scripts), and I'm guessing those aren't its only two issues.

Comment: Per usual I agree with @ChipBennett you should get a better theme. That said I think part of your problem is that jquery-ui is the wrong handle to use. WordPress has the individual parts of the jquery-ui library separated. You need to add  'jquery-ui-core' and whatever other components you need. See the whole list at http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#Default_Scripts_Included_and_Registered_by_WordPress . Your theme could be doing other things that are interfering with what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

If that code is written into the theme just like that-- that is, it isn't hooked into `wp_enqueue_scripts` like is should be-- then you can't "undo" this without hacking the theme.

I should add that if the theme has this code in `functions.php` just like that and not hooked then the theme is ***doing it wrong*** and if you had [debugging enabled](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) you'd see this:

> Notice: `wp_deregister_script` was called incorrectly. Scripts and
>   styles should not be registered or enqueued until the
>   `wp_enqueue_scripts`, `admin_enqueue_scripts`, or `login_enqueue_scripts`
>   hooks. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information.

You need to remove the code and (possibly) add this:

```
function enqueue_scripts_wpse_110500() {
  wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','enqueue_scripts_wpse_110500');
```

With that code, WordPress should load jQuery itself automatically.

I would advise against using a theme that is doing something so fundamental as this incorrectly. No telling what other sloppiness there is in the theme.

Comment: hello, thanks . i updated the answer as per your answer. but it still doesn't includes jquery please see updated question

Comment: There is something happening in code not posted. This should not be that hard.